# Морфологический разбор

Tags: морфология

ПОМОГИИИТЕЕЕЕ!!!!!срочно нужна помощь! нужен морфологический разбо слов: железом, бестия, зная, одному, похрамывающие, протиягивающуюся, устремлены, отъезжавших, самых, вертлявым, бегом, необходимо. ПОЖАЛУЙСТА!!!очень срочно!!!

Answer (score 1):

девушка,это совсем не сложно.просто долго расписывать каждое слово. возьмите пример морфологического разбора любого слова и вперёд. я думаю у вас получиться!